# Как вывести элемент(слово) из массива слов? Java

Tags: java

я только начал изучать Java.
Мне нужно вывести из массива нужное слов

```
String [] [] words = 
newString 

{"word1", "word2", "word3"}

{"word4", "word5", "word6"} ;
```

Каким образом я могу это сделать?

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: ну так вы изучаете. что вы изучили в теме массивов? там наверное что-то сказано про это?

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает что код неправильно написан

Comment: Мои глаза, что за дурацкое объявление?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

немного некоректное обьяевление.
так надо -

```
String [] [] words = { {"word1", "word2", "word3"} ,
                       {"word4", "word5", "word6"} };
```

чтобы вывести нужное слово , надо обратиться к элементу по индексу, отсчет элементов начинается с нулевого индекса, т.е. первый элемент в массиве находится под индексом [0] (наверно от сюда происходит шутка, что программист счтитает первгого ребёнка нулевым)  например  :

```
 System.out.println(words[0][1]);
```

вывод `"word2"`
где `[0]` это номер строки , а `[1]` номер элемента в столбце.

если надо вывести `"word6"` - это 2я строка и 3й столбец отнимай от них единицу и получишь  [1][2]

```
System.out.println(words[1][2]);
```

почитай тут https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.4.php  здесь https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/massivy-java либо там https://hr-vector.com/java/massivy-java